# MySQL error on a complex query

Tags: php, mysql, join

I wrote a sql to fetch massages from mysql database table, but it gives this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY `conversations_messages`.`message_date` DESC LIMIT 4' at line 14

This is the sql

```
SELECT 
        `conversations_messages`.`message_date`, 
        `conversations_messages`.`message_date` > `conversations_members`.`conv_last_view` AS `message_unread`, `conversations_messages`.`message_text`, 
        `users`.`username`,`users`.`user_id`,
        `users`.`profile` 
    FROM 
        `conversations_messages` 
    INNER JOIN 
        `users` 
        ON 
        `conversations_messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id` 
    INNER JOIN 
        `conversations_members` 
        ON 
        `conversations_messages`.`conv_id` = `conversations_members`.`conv_id` 
    WHERE 
      ((`conversations_messages`.`user_id` = 104 AND `conversations_members`.`user_id` = 110) 
       OR 
       (`conversations_messages`.`user_id` = 110 AND `conversations_members`.`user_id` = 104))      
       AND 
       (`conversations_messages`.`deltedby1` <> 104 AND `conversations_messages`.`deltedby2` <> 104) 
       AND 
       `conversations_messages`.`message_date` < 1419958804 
 ORDER BY 
       `conversations_messages`.`message_date` DESC LIMIT 4
```

Anyone know how to fix that error please, thank you

Comment: I don't suppose you can set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) for this

Comment: can see any sysntax error on this code, i tried without AND `conversations_messages`.`message_date` < 1419958804  and works fine, but i need that code

Comment: I recreated some dummy tables to match that query on my machine (using mysql), and ran the query without any errors.

I did notice that the query refers to "deltedby1" and "deltedby2", as opposed to "deletedby1" and "deletedby2".  Is that intentional?

Comment: no the deltedby1 and deltedby2 two columns on table. i'm keep getting error, when i use OR instead of AND the error not appear but results are incorrect.
(conversations_messages.deltedby1 <> 104 OR conversations_messages.deltedby2 <> 104) 

also when i remove AND `conversations_messages`.`message_date` < 1419958804 code it runs without any error, i'm not sure why AND cause for a error, thanks

Comment: Random guess: there is some invisible character between `1419958804` and `ORDER BY` UPD: ooops, just noticed it's a 4 days old question